# Type Coercion failed for the same class

Tags: apache-flex

I have a main application(app.swf) which loads a module(profiles.swf) and the profiles module loads another module(member_profile.swf). In member_profile I get member data from the server side where an object of type Member is returned. The object returned contains an array called Jobs holding objects of type MemberJob. In the member_profile module there's a function that takes a parameter of type MemberJob to display the job details. I have a loop that goes through the array returned and calls the function for each array item like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < member.Jobs.length; i++)
     addJob(member.Jobs[i]);
```

I am getting an error at the addJob line:

Type Coercion failed: cannot convert components.classes::MemberJob@19107d81 to components.classes.MemberJob.

And I receive this error always on the second loading of the member_profile module. I mean this module gets loaded when I click a member's name from the profiles module which passes this name as the parameter for the sub module to load the profile of that member including his jobs. So if I chose to see the profile of member "X" the profile is loaded without any errors but if I then click on member "Y" (which causes the sub module to be reloaded with the new parameter) then I get the type coercion error. And if I did the opposite click on "Y" first then "X" the same happens, error in the second load.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: can you post the code for addJob function.. maybe the problem is there

Comment: I assume what happens is that Flash registers a new definition of `components.classes.MemberJob` each time you load the SWF. The second definition, though exactly same in terms of its contents as the first one, is treated as a different type than the default one and hence the error. Either this is a bug or you're missing some compiler parameter to ignore duplicate definitions while working with Flex modules. I haven't worked with Flex modules, hence this is only an assumption.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the addJob method as it does nothing except assigning the values from the job object to the display components, it looks like this:

public function addJob(mj:MemberJob):void
{    
 jobTitle.text = mj.JobTitle;
 jobDescription.text = mj.JobDescription;
 jobLocation.text = mj.JobLocation;
 //and so on
}

Comment: This is probably because your application domains are not correct.  Can you explain which module is loaded into what application domain?  For the simplest cases you can just load all your modules into the same application domain that is a child of the main application's domain.

Comment: I don't specify an application domain when I load a module. I thought it will be loaded in the same domain of the loader application.

Here what I do, in the main application I load the profiles module like this:

moduleLoader.url = "modules/profiles.swf?publicName=" + publicName;

then in profiles module I load the member_profile module like this:

memberProfileLoader.url = "modules/member_profile.swf?memberId=" + memberId;

Answer (score 9):

Re-read the Flex Help section on [Module Domains](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=modular_2.html#201779) and make sure that you've imported the `components.classes::MemberJob` class into the correct domain.

EDIT:

Try putting the following somewhere in your main application file and see if it makes a difference:

```
import components.classes.MemberJob;
private var memberJob:MemberJob;
```

Comment: I don't specify any application domain when loading the modules. So how would I make sure that the MemberJob class is imported into the correct domain?
The first line in the Module Domains section says "By default, a module is loaded into a child domain of the current application domain" so since am not specifying an application domain it means that the module is loaded into the child domain of the current application, right? And there's only one module that uses this class so I understand that when it's loaded it owns the class definition of MemberJob. Or am I getting all this wrong?

Comment: I placed the import statement and the variable declaration in the main application and it did make a difference. Now there's no error.
But I don't understand what happened? 
Is there any other way of solving this issue instead of creating this unused variable in the main application. The main app doesn't need the MemberJob class in anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you please explain how did this solution solved the problem?
Does it mean that whenever I have this problem I should put the import statement and a dummy variable in the main app?

Thanks

Comment: It's a security feature.  Each module acts like it's own application, with the top level being the most trusted.  Classes imported into a modules domain exist in that domain, and if you try to send them to another domain, the runtime throws an error.  If you want to use the class across module domains, you make sure it gets imported into the top level domain.  Make sense?

Comment: If my solution fixed your issue, you could show some thanks by accepting my answer...at the very least it would help your 58% accept rating.